# SQL using pivot to do average of price range in different countries

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a database with restaurants, with their price range (low, medium or high), the country they're in, and a number of reviews (integer).

So a sample output is this:

```
Country |  price range |  score
USA     |  Low         |  5
Italy   |  Med         |  3
England |  High        |  1
USA     |  Med         |  4
```

Now, I need to somehow show the average score per country per range. Meaning the average of each range per country and need to show them using a pivot of course, though I haven't managed to do it. What can I do please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT Country,
AVG(CASE WHEN [price range] = 'low' THEN Score ELSE NULL END) low_Avg,
AVG(CASE WHEN [price range] = 'medium' THEN Score ELSE NULL END) medium_Avg,
AVG(CASE WHEN [price range] = 'high' THEN Score ELSE NULL END) high_Avg
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Country
```

Comment: Thanks!, I've been trying and trying and didn't manage but this worked perfectly.. I prefer it this way as I needed either to use a pivot or cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query via `PIVOT`

```
SELECT  Country AS [Average per Country],
        [Low], [Med], [High]
FROM (
    SELECT [Country], [PriceRange], [Score]
    FROM [dbo].[Restaurants]
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    AVG(Score)
    FOR [PriceRange] IN ([Low], [Med], [High])
) AS PivotTable
```